# can't retrieve integer value of $_POST['files'']

Tags: php

PHP script portion :
`(getting "files = 4" from cpp file)`:

```
$downloaded_files = $_POST['files'];
echo($downloaded_files);
$start = $downloaded_files+2;
```

The problem is `echo($downloaded_files)` is working and shows value as "4" in cpp file but `$start` is always 2.

**How** do I use value of `$_POST['files']` in my program.

Comment: What value are you expecting to get out of it? The file contents? The file size? Have you tried to use `echo '<pre>' . print_r($array, true) . '</pre>';`

Comment: check the datatype of $downloaded_files and convert it to int value for addition.

Comment: Don't you mean `count($downloaded_files)`?

Comment: files=4. I just want an integer value assigned to 'files'. print_r is working fine. But I need to use $start as 2+$_POST['files']. How to do that??

Comment: Okay so am I understanding this correctly, this has _nothing_ to do with files - you're simply sending a number with POST and want to read it from php. You can cast it to an integer using `$start = (int)$downloaded_files + 2;`. `intval` should also work - if it doesn't try to use `var_dump($downloaded_files)` to see what's actually in there.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried intval($_post[''files]) but it returns 0.

Comment: (int)$downloaded_files + 2 even this doesnt worked :( I cant use var_dump() as I see my output only through cpp file. and cpp file only shows whatever is echo() from php.. I need to use $_POST[] value in php and then proceed... please help!

Comment: count($downloaded_files) this dint work!

Comment: @Viswanath I see gettype ($downloaded_files)as NULL .. I think this is the problem. How to solve it??

Comment: first check what you are getting in $downloaded_files by using var_dump function, If you get an integer then you can add or else you need to typecast your variable by (int)

Comment: I think your $_POST files does not contain any value, are you submitting your form properly. to refer how to create html form for upload refer https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

Comment: yea.. var_dump returned null. but why echo worked I stilll dont know. And here I am using post of Qt to send the data. and not html forms

Answer (score 0):

I'll explain a couple of differences between `echo`, `var_dump` and `array`'s.

**Example echo's**

```
$test = 'Hello, I am a test';
$second_test = 'Hi! I am a second test';

echo $test; // displays: Hello, I am a test
echo $second_test; // displays: Hi! I am a second test

echo $test . ' --- ' . $second_test; // displays: Hello, I am a test --- Hi! I am a second test
```

Echo's are being used to display a single item.

> **Documentation:**
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

---

**Examples var_dump's and array's**

```
$test        = 'Hello, I am a string';
$second_test = [
    'one'   => 'Wassup', // outcome: Wassup
    'two'   => $test, // outcome: Hello, I am a string
    'three' => (1 + 2) // outcome: 3
];
$third_test  = [
    $fourth_test = [
        'sup' => $second_test['two'], // outcome: Hello I am a string
    ],
];
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($test);
echo '</pre>';
//displays:
//string(20) "Hello, I am a string"

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($second_test);
echo '</pre>';
// displays:
//array(3) {
//  ["one"]=>
//  string(6) "Wassup"
//  ["two"]=>
//  string(20) "Hello, I am a string"
//  ["three"]=>
//  int(3)
//}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($third_test);
echo '</pre>';
// displays:
//array(1) {
//  [0]=>
//  array(1) {
//      ["sup"]=>
//    string(20) "Hello, I am a string"
//  }
//}
```

> **Documentation:**
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

**So related to what you need**

Please use this code to see what the outcome is:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST['files']);
echo '</pre>';
```

If the outcome is an array, you can look at the second example on how to display the results.

I hope this will give you an idea on how to handle your `$_POST['files']`.

I will update my answer meanwhile.

**Edit #1:**

```
$downloaded_files = $_POST['files'];
echo($downloaded_files);
$start = $downloaded_files+2;
```

Change it to: (note: there are a couple of other ways to get the same result. But I would like to see what happens).

```
$downloaded_files = $_POST['files'];
$start            = ($downloaded_files + 2);
```

You could also do a `var_dump($_POST)`, to see how many and which items are inside `$_POST`.

**Edit #2:**
Please use the following code:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

I need to know what is inside your `$_POST`.

Comment: in cpp file I am using post(request, data) 
QString files_str = "files="+files+"&";
 QByteArray data;
 data.append(files_str.toUtf8());

so there is just one value and not any array. hence when I used var_dump(), it messes up with my code.

Comment: $downloaded_files = $_POST['files'];
$start            = ($downloaded_files + 2);

this dint work!!

Comment: @shwetasrivastav, you really need to start from the beginning. Don't go ahead ;-), it will be very messy. Please start at step one. Give me the results from `var_dump($_POST)`. I want to know what is inside `$_POST`.

Comment: but then why my echo($downloaded_files) shows correct output

Comment: Which means $_POST is EMPTY!(!!!) $downloaded_files is showing output, because you always ADD 2. (which means: 0+2 = 2). Please make sure $_POST is not empty, otherwise you can never debug this. (or you simple make it hardcoded like: `$downloaded_files = ( !empty($_POST['files'])) ? $_POST['files'] : 4;`

Answer (score 0):

I was making a terrible mistake in my cpp file. I was using post to send 'files=4' and then I used get later on in which i wanted $start value.  so after get(), it was reading php script again. so $downloading_files  was set to 0 this time. so this all happened! finally i skipped using get and continued with my reply of post in cpp. This solved my issue.

THANKS for your help btw :)